# Content with 100% between header and footer and no scroll

Tags: html, css

Example: www.mindout.com.br

I want a fullcontent no scroll on my page but isn't working, the footer is below the content, generating the scrollbar.

the images become large and occupy the entire space, throwing the footer down

```
     <style type="text/css">.content{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: green;
    position: absolute;}.header, #footer {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;}body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;}​.look{width: 100%;height: 100%;}.bg1{
    background: #000000 url(./assets/bone1.jpg) !important;
    background-size: cover !important;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    display: block;
        float: left;
    }
.bg2{
    background: #000000 url(./assets/modelo1.jpg) !important;
    background-size: cover !important;
height: 100%;
width: 50%;
display: block;
    float: left;}

 <div class="content">
  <div class="header">
    <header class="site-header"> 
        <div class="header-wrapper">
            <div class="site-branding">
                <div class="site-logo">
                    <a href="https://www.mindout.com.br/" rel="home">
                        <img src="./assets/logo-transparente.png" alt="MINDOUT">
                    </a>
                </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="nav">
                <nav class="main-navigation-slices">                    
                    <ul class="menu-menu-primario">
                        <li><a href="http://www.mindout.com.br/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">COLLECTIONS</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>                
                </nav>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</div>
<div class="look">
    <div class="bg1"></div>
    <div class="bg2"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer">This is my footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can start by adding `margin:0` to your body. what do you expect to happen when the body content is too long for the  page?

Comment: hi pete, thanks for your help, but the problems are in the images, if I put any text or other type of content works without problems, however the images do create a larger content and generate the scroll bar, what I wanted was for the footer to be over the image without generate the scroll bar

Comment: I still don't understand, if your images are too large to be seen and you have no scrollbar, isn't that going to be bad usability?  If you are not bothered about a scrollbar then just fix position your footer and then hide the overflow on your body - it's dirty but seems to suit your needs

Comment: look at this example https://www.mindout.com.br/__novo.html   I would like to do the same in this example, however in this example it is a purchased code, I would like to make a manual

Comment: Did you try to do inspect on that page you like? or search some height and width properties to see how they work with overflow and responsive design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your body or your page container's height to 100vh with an overflow of hidden, this will make it so that all the content of the page will be no taller than the browser window.

Then include your header and main.

Your main element where your main content will be should as large or larger than the browser height you can force this by setting the height to 100%.

Finally set the footer to have a position of fixed at the bottom of the screen.

I have included a demo below

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background: blue;
}

footer {
  background: red;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

main {
  height: 100%;
}

.pannel {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background: green;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
  <header>header</header>
  <main>
    <div class="pannel">
      <span class="center">pannel</span>
    </div>
    <div class="pannel">
      <span class="center">pannel</span>
    </div>
  </main>
 
 <footer>footer</footer>
```